# Flutter plugin as a binary or library

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, android-native-library

Is it possible to make flutter plugin as a library,so that it can be used and add as a dependency to another flutter app?

I have created a flutter plugin,that plugin uses jar file as a dependency,and i had add the functionality of bluetooth connection to a device.Now i want that plugin to be shared with other developers as a library,so that they can just add the whole file as a dependency and they start working on it. so i want alternatives to make this work ,without publishing into pub.dev ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Comment: @AlejandroCumpa what is the binary for flutter plugin. can you just clarify me